# Stack missing calls in recursion Java

Tags: java, search, recursion, stack, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup parser and want to make some recursion calls to find all the tags that matchs my keyword..
The problem is that the stack calls ends with first tags when it finds no children, (the first if test) and don't finish the rest off calls.

```
    public Set<Element> deepSearch(Element node,String keyword)
{
    Pattern  searchKeyPattern= Pattern.compile(keyword);
    Set<Element> matchedTags = new HashSet<Element>();
    System.out.println("Node name = " + node.tagName()+" || Node children = " + node.children().size());
    if(searchKeyPattern.matcher(node.ownText()).find())
    {
        matchedTags.add(node);
        System.out.println("matched");
    }
    if(node.childNodeSize()==0)
    {
        System.out.println("No children found");
        return matchedTags;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("else the recursive nested call");
        return deepSearch(node.children().iterator().next(),keyword);
    }
}
```

this is the result of the console prints :

> Node name = html || Node children = 2 else the recursive nested call
>   Node name = head || Node children = 10 else the recursive nested call
>   Node name = meta || Node children = 0 No children found

this url I used for testing is this [link](https://www.randomlists.com/phone-numbers)

Is there a problem with my calls, or something I miss ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the method fails is that you are using the children() method on the Element each time you iterate to the next occurrence. You are going 1-level deeper on each call and when you go from html > head > meta inside the meta tag there are no children, hence why your code fails. Feel free to send me a message to help you out with your code since I've coded a few Jsoup-dependant web-crawlers.

IMO you are over-complicating the way you are looking for the phone numbers. Just parse the document and get the element with ID "result", since that is the ol (ordered-list) where the phone numbers you want to extract are stored. Use the .text() method and you will get what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Alex for replying, as You said the problem was with the iterator i believe, I changed  it with a for loop and know it returns more tags.. the phone number are just test, i'm looking to find a tag withing a specific keyword, not phone numbers..

Comment: If an answer is correct you should mark it to prevent further replies and such.